# VBScript - Last Piece of String

Tags: string, vbscript, split, explode

I'm working with a SVN post-commit hook, and need to extract the last piece of info after a `\` in a path.

Basically I need to get `testName` from:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WANDisco\uberSVN\testName
```

Where that string is in a variable, `repoName`.

Completely wrong language, but in PHP, i'd `explode()` the string at the `\`, then get the last item in the array. I hope this is easy, but VBScript is completely foreign to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6dw7aeh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\WANDisco\uberSVN\testName")
Set repoName = objFSO.GetFileName(objFile)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get a file name from a path?  If so the proper way to do this in VBScript is with a [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) like so:

```
dim filesys, filename, path
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
path = filesys.GetAbsolutePathName("c:\somefile.txt")
getname = filesys.GetFileName(path)
```

If you really just want to split a string, use: [VBScript Split function](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_split.asp)